# Equivalent of C++ set container in C

Tags: c++, c, set, containers

I am required to convert some C++ codes to C and I am having some problems regarding the STL container. In the original C++ code, set container is used as in `set< pair<int, int>, sortMapped> mySet;` where sortMapped is a custom comparator to "sort" the entry by mapped value instead of the key value. And of course basic insertion, removal and iterator are included in the original C++ code as well.

So my problem is, does anyone knows the C equivalent of such "always sorted" container where I can write my own comparator as well? Thank you.

Comment: C does not have standard containers, you have to write your own.

Comment: just to give you an idea, C doesn't even have a dedicated type for the strings, with C you only have a collection of really primitive types and no containers at all, at least not the ones that you are used with in C++, in C the equivalent concept of a C++ container can be an basic array of data and it comes with no methods/function attached so if you want something more than an array you have to write everything on your own.

Comment: @Ken, haven't other people already written any and shared them for others to use? Or must everyone write their own? Aren't there third-party developers in the C world?

Comment: @RobKennedy feel free to browse the internet, but, third part code = license terms, for example http://sglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: As I have very less experience on C I doubt I will be able to write my own container. I search a bit and I was wondering is GliB balanced binary tree suitable for me in this case? Or any other custom 3rd party library?

Comment: There are several existing question asking for c container libraries. At least one appears in the "Related" sidebar.

Comment: What do license terms have to do with it, @Ken? It's an overstatement to suggest that the only solution for something that's absent from the language is to write your own.

Comment: @RobKennedy do you know how much is important to own the property of your code and what this differs from every possible licenses out there ? Owning the property on your code is ALWAYS the best solution, that's why all the software houses in every market build their own stuff, sometimes they even build their own middleware. For example EA has its own STL library.

Comment: @Ken: the license terms of the library you pointed to, http://sglib.sourceforge.net/, seem pretty liberal (basically, you're not allowed to remove the copyright).  But yes, if you want to incorporate 3rd party code, you need to deal with the terms.  However, they aren't always problematic.

Comment: @MichaelBurr not enough, it's not even close to something ready for the business, also you are avoiding the concept of property, it depends on what is the purpose of this project and how much they care about it, considering that they are doing this probably it's a school homework or something like that.

Comment: @Ken: I agree that it depends on the purpose of the project.  As important as the license terms would be the quality of the library.  However, it would be a mistake to out of hand jump to the conclusion that you *must* implement your own, just as it would be a mistake to assume you'll certainly find the perfect thing on the internet, free of cost or obligation.

Comment: *All* the software houses in *every* market, @Ken? That's proven false with a single counterexample: I work for a software house, and we use libraries we didn't write. But that's not the point. The point is that whatever obstacles might exist regarding compatibility of licenses, your claim that "you have to write everything on your own" is not true. You don't *have* to write *everything* yourself.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such container within the C language. C does not have nice things like STL and so I think you will just have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices

1. Write code for a binary tree.
2. Write code for a B-Tree.
3. Write code for a hash table.
4. Think of another solution to the problem that might be simpler to write in C.

... And I probably missed off a few other data structures - but it rather depends on the nature and usage of the data in question.

**EDIT**

You can always Google the data structures that I have mentioned above to get examples of code to work from.

Answer (score 0):

> does anyone knows the C equivalent of such "always sorted" container
>   where I can write my own comparator as well?

The simplest, it is an array, that is sorted by using `qsort()` after every change.
With `qsort()` you can write own comparators.

With `bsearch()`, you can add functionality of `std::set` to it.

It is really cheap operation to find items from the sorted array.
But inserting is quite expensive operation. So, this is not solution for all time critical applications.